# Android BLE connecting directly via address fails

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

So I have this situation.
If I scan for new LE devices and connect to any device found, I'm able to connect successfully, but If I store that device address in memory, turn off app and turn on again and then try to connect directly in my onConnectionStateChange I get newState as BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED most of the time, but not always.

This seems to happen on galaxy s7, but not on my other cheap tablet.

My connection logic looks like this:

```
    BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(
            device.getAddress());
    Log.i(TAG, "Found device: " + bluetoothDevice.getAddress()
            + " (" + bluetoothDevice.getName() + ") Type: " + bluetoothDevice.getType());
    bluetoothGatt = bluetoothDevice.connectGatt(context, false, new BluetoothGattCallback() { <..> }, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE);
```

My onConnectionStateChange method looks like this:

```
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            Log.i(TAG, "New connection state: " + newState);
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Connection successful");
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
                        gatt::discoverServices, DELAY_BEFORE_DISCOVERING);

            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                if (status == CONNECTION_ERROR) { // Error 133
                    Log.i(TAG, "Connection error. Trying again.");
                    connect(device);
                } else {
                    bluetoothGatt.close();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected");
                }
            }
        }
```

Log looks like this:

> `2019-03-06 08:26:20.415 5905-5905/app I/LeBluetoothDevice: Write status: true
>   2019-03-06 08:26:20.417 5905-7919/app I/LeBluetoothDevice: Characteristic write status: 0
>   2019-03-06 08:26:21.069 5905-9996/app V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
>   2019-03-06 08:26:26.151 5905-7919/app D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=8 clientIf=9 device=00:0D:19:00:88:D5
>   2019-03-06 08:26:26.153 5905-7919/app I/LeBluetoothDevice: New connection state: 0
>   2019-03-06 08:26:26.154 5905-7919/app D/BluetoothGatt: close()
>   2019-03-06 08:26:26.155 5905-7919/app D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=9
>   2019-03-06 08:26:26.163 5905-7919/app I/LeBluetoothDevice: Disconnected`

Any suggestions on how to handle this would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) also make use of your `BluetoothGattCallback` here.  Discovering services triggers `BluetoothGattCallback.onServicesDiscovered()`.  You should make use of that callback in your scheduling.

I've found that it's best to implement a retry loop with a delay.  That way, when the connection *does* fully initialize immediately you get a better experience.  Try immediately, and if the callback hasn't fired within 2-300ms, try again, then again, etc. until you feel you've tried long enough.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so my issue was with DELAY_BEFORE_DISCOVERING which was ~600 ms. It appears samsung galaxy s7 needs at least 1500ms here. With it I was able to connect every time I tried.

Comment: After onConnectionStateChange return success I waited 600ms before calling discoverServices. Needed to wait longer